# How can I access ruby/rails app variables through an external JS file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building an in house application that is meant to track paid search advertising performance.

Lets say I have a few different paid search campaigns that lead traffic to different sites (lets call them "target sites").  When a user clicks on a paid ad and lands on the target site, a cookie is set using JS.  I then look for the presence of that cookie and if it is set (meaning they must've come from adwords), I swap out the default phone number on the page to a tracking number.

I accomplish this by referencing a JS file in my rails app from the target site like so:

```
<script src="http://www.myapp.com/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Applicable contents of the JS script:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("gclid") > -1) {
       document.cookie = "ppc=adwords; path=/";
    }


function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
        }
    }

    return "";
}


var value = getCookie('ppc'); 
if (value != '') { 
  // this user has the cookie, which means they came from gclid
    alert("this user has the ppc cookie!");

    var testswap = function(){
        var swap = document.getElementById("test").textContent;
        document.getElementById("test").textContent = "New Number Insert";
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", testswap);

} else { 

    alert("user doesn't have cookie");
  // this user lacks the cookie, which means they came from somewhere else
}
```

I store each account's paid search number in the app's database.  What is the best way to access it so that I could swap in the number in this line from the above script

```
document.getElementById("test").textContent = "New Number Insert from app's database";
```

I thought I had this solved by using the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) but quickly realized that it won't be able to access the variables set in the controller on the target site (I know this sounds obvious but I thought maybe once the target site ref the JS file, the JS file could access these).  Is AJAX the way to go?

Disclaimer:  I'm still pretty new when it comes to programming so I apologize if this rundown could have been more concise.  Also, I know this probably isn't the most efficient code so I'm sorry if that makes it a bit more complicated to explain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can make another controller which would search the user's number via the cookie (or any other value that relates to the user's number) then get it via ajax.

Note: Untested Code

Controller (configure your routes as well):

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def get_number
     @cookie = params[:cookie]
     @user = User.where(cookie: @cookie).first
     render json: @user.to_json
   end 
 end
```

Then in your `application.js`

```
  $.get("<your controller route>",{cookie: value},function(data){
      var testswap = function(){
          var swap = document.getElementById("test").textContent;
          document.getElementById("test").textContent = data.number;
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ace.  Correct me if I'm wrong but your controller code assumes that the user visiting the target site is also visiting the application (they would need to in order to grab that cookie "params[:cookie]") right?  The user visiting the target site, never comes to the actual application.  I need the javascript to be able to grab a number from the database so that I can swap with the number in place on the target site.

Comment: how about you ajax request to your application (keep in mind though that there should be a key to know who is passing, otherwise its a security threat)? instead of:  $.get("<your controller route>"), it becomes $.get("http://yourapp.com/your_controller_route", {cookie...)